# Convert integer to words of specific length

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation, character-encoding, named-characters

Assume we give the value from 1 to 26 to alphabets a,b,...,z.

Now given an integer ($n$) i like to generate words of specific length ($l$) that sum of them equals $n$. For instance, if
$n=10$, $l=3$;

```
{aah,abg,acf,ade,aed,afc,agb,aha,bag,bbf,bce,bdd,bec,bfb,bga,caf,cbe,ccd,cdc,ceb,cfa,dae,dbd,dcc,ddb,dea,ead,ebc,ecb,eda,fac,fbb,fca,gab,gba,haa}
```

with more clear representation:

```
{aah,abg,acf,ade,aed,afc,agb,aha,
bag,bbf,bce,bdd,bec,bfb,bga,
caf,cbe,ccd,cdc,ceb,cfa,
dae,dbd,dcc,ddb,dea,
ead,ebc,ecb,eda,
fac,fbb,fca,
gab,gba,
haa}
```

How can I write this code in Mathematica. Is teere any predefine function to do this job for me?

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

n = 10; l = 3;
letters = Alphabet[];
iparts = IntegerPartitions[n, {l}];
idx = Permutations /@ iparts // Flatten[#, 1] & // Sort
idx // Map[letters[[#]] &] // Map[StringJoin] // 
  SplitBy[#, StringTake[#, 1] &] & // Grid
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

You can get the list called `res`, and for cases such as follows:

```
n = 10; l = 5;
res = idx // Map[letters[[#]] &] // Map[StringJoin] // 
    SplitBy[#, StringTake[#, 1] &] &)
```

For a different presentation, try:

```
Framed /@ res // Column
```

Comment: thans @Syed, when I change $l$ to bigger integer, the representation is splitting to separate lines, is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: ps. thans->thanks

Comment: How big is "bigger"? Anything involving integer partitions and permutations reaches its limits soon. Or are you talking about the presentation part?

Comment: for instance I set l=5, it splits each word in 4 lines! please see the output image here: https://ibb.co/qrqDCn0

Comment: Can't display what can't fit on the screen. Use `(res = idx // Map[letters[[#]] &] // Map[StringJoin] // 
    SplitBy[#, StringTake[#, 1] &] &) // Grid`. This way the variable `res` will have the list that you can use as you please.

Comment: it is the same as before! If I only need as much as possible words starting with the same initial in the same line and continue on the next line. Then go to the next initial alphabet in new line.

Answer (score 3):

```
Words[wordSum_, letterCount_] :=
  StringJoin[Part[Alphabet[], #]] & /@ 
    Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[wordSum, {letterCount}], 1];

Words[10, 3]
(*   
   {haa,aha,aah,gba,gab,bga,bag,agb,abg,fca,fac,cfa,caf,afc,acf,fbb,bfb,bbf,
    eda,ead,dea,dae,aed,ade,ecb,ebc,ceb,cbe,bec,bce,ddb,dbd,bdd,dcc,cdc,ccd} 
*)
```

From that you can apply whatever sorting and presentation you want.

For example, if `words` is the result of `Words[10,3]` (I've prettified the output, it's just a list of lists):

```
GatherBy[Sort[words], StringTake[#, 1] &]
(*
  {{"aah", "abg", "acf", "ade", "aed", "afc", "agb", "aha"},
   {"bag", "bbf", "bce", "bdd", "bec", "bfb", "bga"}, 
   {"caf", "cbe", "ccd", "cdc", "ceb", "cfa"}, 
   {"dae", "dbd", "dcc", "ddb", "dea"}, 
   {"ead", "ebc", "ecb", "eda"}, 
   {"fac", "fbb", "fca"}, 
   {"gab", "gba"}, 
   {"haa"}}
*)
```

Wrapping that with `Grid` might be what you want for final display.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

```
StringJoin@*FromLetterNumber/@Pick[#,
  ContainsNone[{0}]/@#]& [FrobeniusSolve[{1,1,1},10]]

 (* {aah,abg,acf,ade,aed,afc,agb,aha,bag,bbf,bce,bdd,bec,bfb,bga,
     caf,cbe,ccd,cdc,ceb,cfa,dae,dbd,dcc,ddb,dea,ead,ebc,ecb,eda,
     fac,fbb,fca,gab,gba,haa} *)
```

---

**Original Answer**

```
StringJoin@*FromLetterNumber/@Pick[#,Total/@#,10]&[Tuples[Range[10],{3}]]


(* {aah,abg,acf,ade,aed,afc,agb,aha,bag,bbf,bce,bdd,bec,bfb,bga,
    caf,cbe,ccd,cdc,ceb,cfa,dae,dbd,dcc,ddb,dea,ead,ebc,ecb,eda,
    fac,fbb,fca,gab,gba,haa} *)
```

Or

```
StringJoin@*FromLetterNumber /@ Catenate[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[26, 
  {3}]] // Sort // Short

(* {aax,abw,acv,adu,aet,afs,agr,ahq,<<284>>,ucb,uda,vac,vbb,vca,wab,wba,xaa} *)
```

Just for fun

```
 StringJoin@*FromLetterNumber /@ Catenate[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[26, 
  {8}]] // Sort // Short

(* {aaaaaaas,aaaaaabr,aaaaaacq,aaaaaadp,aaaaaaeo,<<480691>>,
    raabaaaa,rabaaaaa,rbaaaaaa,saaaaaaa} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

A 2-liner?

```
  FromCharacterCode /@ (Permutations /@ 
   Select[Tuples[Range[26], 3], (Total[#] == 10 &)]+ToCharacterCode["a"][[1]]-1)
   //Flatten// Union

   {"aah", "abg", "acf", "ade", "aed", "afc", "agb", "aha", "bag", 
     "bbf", "bce", "bdd", "bec", "bfb", "bga", "caf", "cbe", "ccd", 
     "cdc", "ceb", "cfa", "dae", "dbd", "dcc", "ddb", "dea", "ead", 
     "ebc", "ecb", "eda", "fac", "fbb", "fca", "gab", "gba", "haa"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get ways of expressing the number `sum` as `len` digits between 1 and 26:

```
 expressions = 
   FromLetterNumber /@ IntegerPartitions[sum, {len}, Range@26];
```

And get all the permutations of each expression:

```
Flatten[Permutations /@ expressions, 1] // Sort;
```

As a function for general input, producing your desired output format:

```
getWords[sum_, len_] :=
 (
  expressions = 
   FromLetterNumber /@ IntegerPartitions[sum, {len}, Range@26];

  perms =Flatten[Permutations /@ expressions, 1] // Sort;


GatherBy[ StringJoin /@ perms, StringPart[#, 1] &] // Grid
  )
```

And reproducing your example:

```
getWords[10, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]